# Check for same column value in different text files?

Tags: python

Say I got two text files, each having two columns:

```
text1.txt           text2.txt

col1   col2         col1   col2   

1      9            3      6
2      8            4      7
3      7            5      8
4      6            6      9
```

I now want to read in both files and check for same values in `col1`. Then I want to create a new text file containing three columns: the first one with the identical value, and the other two colums with the corresponding value of `col2` of each file. So for the example above the new text file should look like this:

`new_text.txt`

```
col1   col2   col3 

3      7      6     
4      6      7
```

Since 3 and 4 both appear in `col 1` in both files.
What would be an efficient way to do that?

Comment: What approach(es) have you tried so far?

Comment: What is separating the columns, space or tab characters?

Comment: @crumb nothing much yet, just started to think about it. I thought about reading in the files, concatenate the lines in a new list and search for identical values in this list, but that does not seem efficient to me.


@martineu I guess space separated? Because I created the text file by saving the corresponding 2-D lists via `np.savetxt()`. I am not sure what it chooses as a seperator. How can I check that? Sorry but I am pretty new to all of this. But I can read the files via `np.loadtxt()`which gives me the corresponding 2-D list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3,

```
with open('text3.txt', 'w') as file3:
    print('col1\tcol2\tcol3', file=file3)
    with open('text1.txt', 'r') as f:
        file1 = f.readlines()
    with open('text2.txt', 'r') as f:
        file2 = f.readlines()
    for i in file1[1:]:
        line1 = i.split()
        for j in file2[1:]:
            line2 = j.split()
            if line1[0] == line2[0]:
                row = line1[0] + '\t' + line1[1] + '\t' + line2[1]
                print(row, file=file3)
```

A naive way to make the operation work is to iterate both files in a nested way and search for instances where `col1` in the first file equals to `col1` in the second file.

I strongly suggest you try the package [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/). The required operation can be easily done through a simple inner [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) function using pandas.

An example can be

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('text1.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv('text2.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col1', how='inner')
df3.to_csv('text3.txt', index=False, sep=" ")
```

Comment: Thanks! So how would it work with the join function?

Comment: I added an inner join example to post.

Comment: merge() function is great stuff!

Answer (score 1):

```
f1=open(file1,"r")
f2=open(file2,"r")

lines1=f1.readlines()
lines2=f2.readlines()

text1=[[]]
text2=[[]]

for x in lines1:
   text1.append(x.split(' ')[0],x.split(' ')[1]) // replace ' ' with the seperator between columns 
for x in lines2:
   text2.append(x.split(' ')[0],x.split(' ')[1]) // replace ' ' with the seperator 
f.close()
```

then loop over each 2d lists to generate 3rd one with the col1 values and col2/col3 with corresponding of col2 of both text files 1 and 2 as required

Comment: Thanks! I'll emphasize that I can easily get a 2-D list of my text file via `np.loadtxt(text1.txt)`. So I guess `readlines()` and `append()` to create the 2-D list seems unnecessary?